# Replay, with python, a puppeteer script exported from Chrome Recorder

Tags: python, pyppeteer

I made a recording with Chrome's recorder, then exported it to a json file:

[image]

Now I'd like to replay this "script" using python. The de facto package seems to be [`pyppeteer`](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer). I can run scripts written in python itself, but am trying to run the script I recorded (and exported to json) itself.